# can't read a json come from insta

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, instagram, instagram-api

i make a project like this but in the parse a json file come from instagram api i cant read it 
my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>tst</title>
<script src="../jq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".send").click(function(){
        var name =  $("#name").val();
        var my_url= "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/"+name+"?access_token=2307573123.2c01fc8.d2a19d4145c84d59962c0db8d418d2a8";
        $("#name").val("");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: my_url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            function(response){
                //how????
            }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <input type="search" id="name" />
  <input type="button" class ="send"  value="send" />
</body>
</html>
```

i want to just read a reson .i can pars it but i cant read it.
//where i put **how???** is my place to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in ajax call, not getting response properly, it should be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".send").click(function(){
    var name =  $("#name").val();
    var my_url= "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/"+name+"?access_token=2307573123.2c01fc8.d2a19d4145c84d59962c0db8d418d2a8";
    $("#name").val("");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: my_url,
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    }).done(function(response){
            //response is our object with data
        }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: tnx a lot.my problem solved.i will accept your answer as sson as possibel :)

Answer (score 1):

The API response contains a data property :

GET : https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/stackoverflow?access_token=xxx

```
{"data": {"name": "stackoverflow", "media_count": 10769}, "meta": {"code": 200}}
```

To access values :

```
success:function(response){
  //how????
  alert(response.data.name + ' have ' + response.data.media_count + ' media');
}
```

Comment: should be `success:function(response) { ... }`